# Highlight a mystery

Tags: vba, debug, ide

What the heck is the vba editor trying to tell me with this:
[image: unknown vba editor highlight]

Comment: that is user set stopping point.  Click on the red circle and it will go away.  Otherwise the code will stop when it hits that line.

Comment: That's a debugger breakpoint.  Will only have any effect if a debugger is attached.  It means "break here".  It will have no effect at all when running without a debugger.

Comment: @Zer0 the fact that the VBE is part of Excel it will stop.

Comment: @ScottCraner Edited for clarity (applies to all breakpoints).  Wasn't aware the debugger is always attached and running in this case.  Thanks.